# Incompatible operand types Die and Int

Tags: java

Brand new to stackoverflow so forgive me if I make any mistakes. 
I'm trying to learn Java right now and I've been having some trouble with my if statements. 
In the following block of code, I've been getting an error:

```
if (die1 == 7) {

  }
```

**Incompatible operand types die and int**

I know what the error is telling me to fix, but I'm not quite sure how to go about and actually fix it.

Any tips?

Comment: What type of object is die1?

Comment: Does the dice have a face value?

Comment: what is the data type for `die1`? Is it an `int`?

Comment: @blahfunk Oops, I forgot. Apologies.

Die1 is actually part of a different class. ( http://pastebin.com/xb0C3X2M )
The current class is here. It's a work in progress so variables are astray: (http://pastebin.com/a8m4pXZv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (die1.getFaceValue() == 7) {...}
```

You can't compare the object die1 with the int 7. You have to compare "objects" or types that are the same or can be compared. Calling the *getFaceValue()* method of die1 will fix the issue.

Comment: Hey, that worked! Thank you very much for the help. I'll have to look into FaceValues a bit more.