# Comparing enum and Long

Tags: java

I've got a simple enum and in my main() i want to compare this enum to `Long` variable, but I have an error `HelloWorld.java:15: error: incomparable types: Long and myEnum System.out.println(x == myEnum.ENUM_A);`. How to repair it and compare it correctly?

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public enum myEnum {
            ENUM_A(1), 
            ENUM_B(2), 
            ENUM_C(3);
     
            int n;
     
            private myEnum(int n) {
                this.n = n;
            }
     }
     public static void main(String []args){
        Long x = 1L;
        System.out.println(x == myEnum.ENUM_A);
     }
}
```

Comment: introduce a getter in enum  `getN()`and check like this `System.out.println(x == myEnum.ENUM_A.getN());`

Comment: thanks, It's a good solution. But if i want to compare directly Long and enum using == comparator - what sould i do?

Comment: You can't compare different types using `==`

Comment: `==` is used to compare primitive values like `int`or `long`. Since your `x` is of type of the wrapper class `Long` you need to use the `equals` method, i.e. `System.out.println(x.equals(Long.valueOf(myEnum.ENUM_A.n)));`

Comment: Possibly related: [Incompatible operand types Die and Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333238/incompatible-operand-types-die-and-int)

Comment: I admit I’m surprised about the compile-time error. I would have expected the code to compile and print `false` because `x` and `myEnum.ENUM_A` are two different objects. I have reproduced the compile error, though. And learned.

Comment: From JLS: *It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal (ignoring the case where both values are null).* You can neither cast a `Long` to a `myEnum` nor vice versa. Therefore the equality operation is a compile-time error. [JLS link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a getN() to your enum:

```
public enum myEnum {
  ENUM_A(1),
  ENUM_B(2),
  ENUM_C(3);

  int n;

  private myEnum(int n) {
     this.n = n;
  }

  public int getN() {
     return n;
  }
}
```

and then in your main do `System.out.println(x == myEnum.ENUM_A.getN());`

If you need to compare any value, in your case a long with your enum, you will need to get the value of the enum.

Another alternative to the `==` is `Objects` from the java.util

```
Objects.equals(value1, value2)
```